# Install error in VS Code - eslint

Tags: node.js, npm, visual-studio-code, eslint

When I try to install eslint (npm i eslint) I get the error 
"`-- eslint@2.7.0  extraneous"

I'm new to npm and vs code. I installed several extensions with no problem, this installed with errors via the ctl-p input box.

Answer (score 1):

"`-- eslint@2.7.0 extraneous" means that this package installed but isn't listed in your package.json.